# View is null in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a number of fragments within a `ViewPager` in one of my activities. These fragments have text on them. My goal is to update the text on the fragments when an event happens in my activity.

I have tried some things, but I cannot seem to find a view to work with. In the below code I have tried to save the view from the `onCreateView` to a private field. This works successfully when creating my fragment, but when I try and call `refresh` my `mView` is null.

`refresh` is implemented in an interface. My `ViewPager` has 2 different fragments, so I implemented the interface to allow me to cast an unknown fragment to call refresh.

I have tried to write the below code to best illustrate my problem. I can set the text to "Hello" but on refresh, the activity will crash because `mView` is null.

```
    private View mView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) { return null; }         
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_account_general, container, false);
        mView = view;
        setContent();
        return view;
    }

    private void setContent() {
        if (mView == null) return;
        ((TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.mId)).setText("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh() {
        ((TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.mId)).setText("Test");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I be doing instead? Fragments are very new to me and I haven't programmed for Android in a long time. My only intention is to update the value of my `TextView` when the `refresh` method is called.

Thank you for any attempts at helping me with my issue!

Edit:
As requested, the exception trace.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jordanmoore.finances.AccountGeneralFragment.refresh(AccountGeneralFragment.java:85)
    at com.jordanmoore.finances.AccountActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(AccountActivity.java:222)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2534)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:964)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1090)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2863)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3538)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: in which activity/fragment life-cycle's method do you call `refresh` method?

Comment: I honestly didn't understand what you want. I swear I've read your question 3 times. It's either my mind is locked, or you're had to understand.

Comment: hahaha, never mind... what i meant to say is: where is your code for calling `refresh` method?  :)

Comment: Sorry, I will try and explain better. I have a ViewPager in my activity which has a few fragments. The fragments have some text on them. When some event happens in my activity, I want to change the text on my fragment. 

My `refresh` method is being successfully called from my activity. For debugging purposes it loops through each fragment in my adapter and calls the refresh method on it. Currently this code is being ran when I press a menu item, so in `onOptionsItemSelected` of my activity.

Comment: can you paste your exception stack trace too? it will help to pinpoint the problem

Comment: I have updated the original post with the stack trace. `AccountGeneralFragment` line 85 is the `setText("Test")` line.

Comment: seems like your view is null when you are calling setText on it. try calling refresh method somewhere in the onResume of your activity

Comment: In onResume it is not null, but that makes sense because onResume follows onCreateActivity in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bottom line- a fragment should be in control of refreshing it's own view. an activity should never call a "refresh" method in a fragment, simply because it's painful and error-prone to determine when the fragment is initialized and ready to render.

in your case, your activity could broadcast an "update", which your fragments register to receive. as long as you ensure you are register after the preconditions have been met, and unregister before the preconditions become invalid, things will work. e.g., follow the typical pattern of registering in `onResume()` on unregistering in `onPause()`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use a local broadcast and can now successfully update my text when an event occurs in my activity. For anybody reading this post in the future, this website provides a good example on how to set up a local broadcast (but when registering the received in the fragment you must use `this.getActivity()` not `this`. Anyway, the website: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#ownreceiver_localbroadcastmanager